# GameClosure: support for browser games?

Tags: android, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs, gameclosure

I'm trying out GameClosure and was wondering if I could create 'normal' HTML5 browser games with it as well (beside Android or iOS apps) ?

Also, does GameClosure only support its own game engine, or could I use something like KineticJS as well?

And are there any plans for supporting WebViews in the future?

Comment: GameClosure has a web site of its very own [here](http://www.gameclosure.com/). Perhaps it would be a better source of information for you.

Comment: I asked and then answered this very question, here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/game-closure-devkit/-W0qbdRUmHY

Comment: Do this inside the project's folder and then look inside the build/release directory: $ basil build browser-desktop

Comment: I think this should be reopened.  And another question would be can KineticJS be integrated while still working for mobile devices?

Comment: This should be three separate questions, that's why it is "too broad."